# My C++ program cannot check Å, Ä or Ö

Tags: c++

```
void kod()  
{     
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"swedish");
    locale swedish("swedish");
    locale::global(swedish);
    char vokal[9] = {'a','o','u','å','e','i','y','ä','ö'};              
    char konsonant[20] = {'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z'};        
    char stor_konsonant[20] = {'B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Z'};   
    string rovarsprak, ord;

    cout << "Skriv in ett ord" << endl;            
    getline (cin,ord);                                             
    int n = ord.length();                          
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)                               
    {
        for (int x = 0; x<20; x++)                     
        {
            if (vokal[x] == tolower(ord[i]))
            {
                rovarsprak = rovarsprak + ord[i];      
            }

            else if(konsonant[x] == ord[i])        
            {
                rovarsprak = rovarsprak + ord[i] + "o" + ord[i];       
            }

            else if(stor_konsonant[x] == ord[i])   
            {
                rovarsprak = rovarsprak + ord[i] + "O" + ord[i];       
            }

            else if(' ' == ord[i])                 
            {
                rovarsprak = rovarsprak + " ";
            }

            else if(ord[i] == 'Ö')
            {
                cout << "Ö";
            }              
        }
    }
    cout << rovarsprak << "\n" << endl;
}
```

I understand the program may be confusing if you don't speak swedish, so I'll try to explain it

The user inputs a word, and the program goes through the word and makes it into "rövarspråket", which means it will put an O in between all consonants, and then repeat it, whilst vowels aren't affected. Etc, "Ber" becomes "Boberor"
This all works fine, but when there is an å,ä or ö in the program, it deletes it, rather than keep it in the word. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Just paste it, select it, and then click the **{ }** button.

Comment: you need to use unicode (not very pretty though in C/C++)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ä</kbd><kbd>å</kbd><kbd>ö</kbd> and friends are not single byte characters, UTF-8 uses multibyte characters for non ASCII chars. That is the reason for your code to fail.

So use `std::string` and a `UTF-8` decoding library (Greg Kroah-Hartman referenced a fast/minimal implementation which is just a tiny header file, writter by **Björn Höhrmann**) if you need single characters or `libiconv` for the real deal.

Comment: So would it be possible for me to use ASCII code instead?

Comment: @drahnr: As far as I know, Greg Kroah-Hartman didn't write such a decoder, but (at https://plus.google.com/+gregkroahhartman/posts/f3fngVm174f) he _referred_ to the one by Björn Höhrmann (at http://bjoern.hoehrmann.de/utf-8/decoder/dfa/) which has some interesting trivia at http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-archive/2013Apr/0041.html

Comment: Mea Culpa, all credit goes to Björn Höhrmann

Answer (score 1):

Other than the character set issue, you have an error in your loops.

You only have 9 vowels,  but you assume you have 20 vowels in the loop.

```
 for (int x = 0; x<20; x++) 
 {
    // ...
   if (vokal[x] == tolower(ord[i]))
```

This is a memory read overrun if x >= 9.

A much better approach would be to create 3 sets of letters, and check each set.

```
#include <set>
//...
  std::set<char> vokal = {'a','o','u','å','e','i','y','ä','ö'};              
  std::set<char> konsonant = {'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z'};        
  std::set<char> stor_konsonant = {'B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Z'};   

    string rovarsprak, ord;
    cout << "Skriv in ett ord" << endl;            
    getline (cin,ord);                                             
    int n = ord.length();                          
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)                               
    {
        if ( voka.find(tolower(ord[i])) != voka.end())
           rovarsprak = rovarsprak + ord[i];      
        else 
        if(konsonant.find(ord[i]) != konsonant.end())
           rovarsprak = rovarsprak + ord[i] + "o" + ord[i];       
        else 
        if(stor_konsonant.find(ord[i]) != stor_konsonant.end())
           rovarsprak = rovarsprak + ord[i] + "O" + ord[i];       
        else 
        if( isspace(ord[i]))
           rovarsprak = rovarsprak + " ";
        else if(ord[i] == 'Ö')
            cout << "Ö";
    }
    cout << rovarsprak << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Given the other answer concerning character set, change the above code accordingly to have sets of the correct character type.  The basic outline will be the same.